# Temperature of coolant before and after radiator

Tags: coolant, radiator, temperature

I am doing an analysis project on radiators so I need to know the input temperature.

At what average temperature does the coolant enter radiator (not thermostat opening temperature) during normal motion?

And at what average temperature does the coolant leave the radiator?

Answer (score 2):

**Too much variance**

This question is too broad.  Different models, engine types, fuel systems, exhaust systems and engine configurations make this impossible to answer.

**If you want to know about your car**

[You can get one of these](https://www.google.com/search?q=infrared%20heat%20detector&oq=infrared%20heat%20detector&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.8439j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) and check various temperature ranges under various circumstances like pulling a load up a hill, driving in city traffic, cruising down the freeway and idling by putting your car under the load, driving for a bit and then stopping and checking yourself using the thermometer.

**if your programming a solution for general use**

If you are looking for a template solution and numbers for a particular app you are writing then I think you need to have a different way of looking at it that's threshold driven for alerting or some such solution.  I think a MaxTemp view is more tenable than seeking averages across all of the various platforms.

Comment: Programically - make 2 pipes with a bung and temp sensor.  Install in your upper and lower radiator hoses.  Connect one side of the temp sensor to 5v, and the other side to an arduino or similar.  Have it output to a laptop or phone.  Will need spec sheets to relate voltage to temperature.

Comment: I think he's trying to do it for an app though. Are there any sensors for hot and cold side radiator ?

Comment: Unlikely.  The sensor is usually near the hot side. Hot side should stay closer to the thermostat opening temperature.  Some vehicles have a separate sender for the gauge, but I don't think it would be close enough to the cold side.

Comment: That's been my belief as well